# showing only one coordinate

Tags: scatter-plot

I have the following but it only shows the coordinate of x, I need both to appeared when the mouse hover on the plot, I tried to do another one for (dc) which is the y coordinate, but nothing is working, I even tried to change `return (dm)` to `return (d)` but it will show (object) instead of the point, any ideas please?

```
pplot.append("title")
   .text(function(d,i) {
       return (dm)
   });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you want to return a String with the `x` and `y` coordinates.

So you should be able to just access each coordinate from the `d` object separately and use the `+` operator to concatenate them:

```
ascatter.append("title")
   .text(function(d,i) {
       return "x: " + d.a + "y: " + d.b;
   });
```

Comment: Thanks so much, I'm just new to JS, but you solved the problem. Thanks again!